# How can I tell Blender not to quit after finishing my script

Tags: python, command-line

So after my Python-Blender script finishes running from the command line, the command line window immediately closes..not giving me a chance to see any feedback, errors, etc. Can I make it not close? It would be super helpful if I can read the errors that my code outputs to the command line window before it closes.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: one idea would be that you write your feedback/error to a txt file - so you can check later ;)

Comment: Open `cmd` and then `cd` to the blender installation path. Then run `blender.exe` or your blender script from that directory. Once you close the exe or the script finishes, your command line will still remain open. Same thing on linux and unix-based systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can python input() method. I use it for
debugging Blender Python scripts both in CLI mode or GUI mode of running Blender.

```
print('1')
input("Press Enter to continue")
print('2')
```

Only catch is that it does not flush the input buffer